# Getting variable names in the output of a for loop run on a pairwise.wilcox.test in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I would like to analyze a bunch of variables from a dataframe "Genes" with categorical data from a dataframe "Drugs" using the pairwise.wilcox.test to account for multiple testing.

My data looks as follows:

Genes:

```
  G1 G2 G3    
A 5  1  3 
B 4  2  1
C 7  6  5
```

Drugs:

```
  D1 D2 D3
A R  S  R
B S  R  S
C R  S  S
```

A, B, C are the sample names in the first column

Now I would like to test the variables G1, G2, G3 one by one with D1, then D2, then D3. In the output I would like to get the variable name "G1" and e.g. "D1" with the respective results.

So far I have only tried an association with one variable (D1) from the "Drugs" dataframe and my code looks as follows:

```
for(i in Genes[2:4]){print(
  pairwise.wilcox.test(i,Drugs$D1, p.adjust.method = "fdr", exact =F, paired = F, alt = "two.sided"))

  dev.off
}
```

The output is however not exactly what I was hoping for:

```
Pairwise comparisons using Wilcoxon rank sum test 

data:  i and Drugs$D1

  R

S 0.23

P value adjustment method: fdr
```

How can I change the code to include the name of the respective variable instead of "i" in the output?

Comment: If your finally output really the output from the function? Or do you want to summarize the results some other way? Normally you would just extract the value you are interesting in calculating and then combine that with the names later if required. Getting the variable name in the output from a for loop requires a messy `do.call()` invocation. It's usually not worth it.

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed in the very end the p-value is what matters from the results, however I would like to be sure I interpret the results correctly and am able to associate the correct variable with each output (my actual data has 400 variables in the one dataset and 4 in the other).